# How to use 'git checkout' command

Tags: git

I think this command below, will checkout a remote branch name 'branch_name' and create a local branch for me called 'branch_name'.

```
'git checkout -b branch_name "`git remote`"/branch_name'
```

My question is

- how can I run this despite I already has a branch name 'branch_name', can I ask git it checkout to branch_name even (if that branch already exist)?
- when I do 'git branch -a', I don't see a branch 'remote/branch_name', I only see a branch 'remotes/ser-git/branch_name'. How can git find the right remove branch from 'git remtoe'/branch_name?

Comment: I would recommend using a git repo viewer to do advance checking out of branches. Something like smartgit http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I run this despite I already has a branch name 'branch_name',
>   can I ask git it checkout to branch_name even (if that branch already
>   exist)?

Use `-B` option instead of `-b`

> when I do 'git branch -a', I don't see a branch 'remote/branch_name',
>   I only see a branch 'remotes/ser-git/branch_name'. How can git find
>   the right remove branch from 'git remtoe'/branch_name?

git resolves reference name in the following order:

1. If `$GIT_DIR/<name>` exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
2. otherwise, `refs/<name>` if it exists;
3. otherwise, `refs/tags/<refname>` if it exists;
4. otherwise, `refs/heads/<name>` if it exists;
5. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<name>` if it exists; **<- this is your case**
6. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<name>/HEAD` if it exists.

It means that if you have local branch `ser-git/branch_name`, it will be preferred by git instead of remote branch.